# Tikzpicture: How to draw a line of given length from current point which ends on x-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the following code. Can I modify the `\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- ++(-30:2);` part in some way to draw a line segment of given length (anything greater than 1, say 3 units) from `(0,1)` such that it ends on positive x axis? (Without having to manually calculate the end point on x axis using Pythagoras theorem.)

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
 \draw[->] (-0.25,0) -- (2.25,0) coordinate (x axis);
     \foreach \x/\xtext in {0, 0.5/\frac{1}{2}, 1, 1.5/\frac{3}{2}, 2}
   \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north,fill=white] {$\xtext$};
     \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- ++(-30:2);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result of above code:

[image: Result of above code]

Comment: You could do `\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- ++(-{asin(1/2)}:2);`, but perhaps you had something different in mind?

Comment: @Torbjørn this is acceptable as an answer to me. I am new to tikz-pgf and I didn't know that I could use inverse trigonometric functions in place of angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angle computation can be done in the coordinate:

```
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- ++({-asin(1/2)}:2);
```

The braces are required as otherwise the parser would confuse the closing parenthesis of `asin` for the closing parenthesis of the coordinate.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
 \draw[->] (-0.25,0) -- (2.25,0) coordinate (x axis);
     \foreach \x/\xtext in {0, 0.5/\frac{1}{2}, 1, 1.5/\frac{3}{2}, 2}
   \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north,fill=white] {$\xtext$};
     \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- ++({-asin(1/2)}:2);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here, a ruler and compass construction using the `intersections` library.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
 \draw[->,name path=abscisses] (-0.25,0) -- (2.25,0) coordinate (x axis);
     \foreach \x/\xtext in {0, 0.5/\frac{1}{2}, 1, 1.5/\frac{3}{2}, 2}
            \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north,fill=white] {$\xtext$};
     %\draw[blue] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- ++(-30:2);
     \path[name path=cercle] (0,1) circle (2cm);
     \path [name intersections={of =cercle and abscisses}];
     \draw (0,0)--(0,1)--(intersection-1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```